# Logic recommendation for React refreshing token

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, jwt, refresh-token

Can anyone suggest me a good logic to automatically refresh my accessToken?

At the moment, I have an **OpenAPI generated class**, where the **accessToken is a promise** in all the requests. In this promise, I check if the token is expired and I fetch the new one, based on a refresh token.

I also have an **AuthContext**, that I use to manage my authtentication, user details, etc. (saving to localstorage, etc)

The problem is that I need somehow to access my AuthContext and to give it the new token or to logout if the token could not be refreshed, in my API class.

I do receive an error on the following code, but this is expected:
`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

My access token as promise (inside the API class)

```js
accessToken: new Promise<string>(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const tokenExpiresAt = Date.parse(model.tokenExpiration);
    const {saveAuth, logout} = useAuth()  // Here is the problem

    // if token is expired, refresh it
    if (tokenExpiresAt < Date.now()) {
        this.Auth.refresh({accessToken: model.token, refreshToken: model.refreshToken})
            .then((response) => {
                // save new auth
                saveAuth(response.data)
                resolve(response.data.token);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // error refreshing token, logout
                logout()
                reject("Token expired");
            });
    }

    resolve(model.token);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem a while ago, yes you cannot call a hook inside a hook so another approach to solve this issue is to intercept the `axios` response interceptor.

```
axiosApiInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response
}, async function (error) {
  const originalRequest = error.config;
  if (error.response.status === 403 && !originalRequest._retry) {
    originalRequest._retry = true;
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
    const access_token = await refreshAccessToken(refreshToken);            
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
    return axiosApiInstance(originalRequest);
  }
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

And you can implement your own `refreshAccessToken` function according to your `usecase`.

Comment: But let's say my token cannot refresh (the refresh token is expired). Then how can I logout?
I need a way to set tell my AuthContext that I am logged out.

Comment: You can set your access token and refresh token to null if this fails. And add a secondary condition to check if you have values set for access token and refresh token or not.